# Mac: `platform-tools` 1.16: `cargo build-sbf` error: failed to run custom build command for `blake3 v1.4.0`

Tags: solana-cli, cli

I seem to be having trouble building a Solana program with CLI version `1.16` on `macOS Ventura 13.4.1`. It appears I have some kind of `clang` linker issue, but I have not been able to debug just yet.

This issue is new as of release `1.16.0` of `platform-tools`.

```
The following warnings were emitted during compilation:

warning: In file included from c/blake3_neon.c:1:
warning: c/blake3_impl.h:4:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
warning: #include <assert.h>
warning:          ^~~~~~~~~~
warning: 1 error generated.

error: failed to run custom build command for `blake3 v1.4.0`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/joesol/Desktop/labs/keyring-program/target/release/build/blake3-39323e39efaeadbe/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_PURE
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_NO_NEON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_NEON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_NO_NEON
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CARGO_FEATURE_PURE
  cargo:rustc-cfg=blake3_neon
  TARGET = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
  HOST = Some("aarch64-apple-darwin")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64-apple-darwin
  CC_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC_aarch64_apple_darwin
  CC_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CC
  HOST_CC = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CC
  CC = Some("/Users/joesol/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.16.1/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/clang")
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin
  CFLAGS_aarch64-apple-darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin
  CFLAGS_aarch64_apple_darwin = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=HOST_CFLAGS
  HOST_CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CFLAGS
  CFLAGS = None
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS
  CRATE_CC_NO_DEFAULTS = None
  DEBUG = Some("false")
  running: "/Users/joesol/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.16.1/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/clang" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=arm64-apple-darwin" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c11" "-o" "/Users/joesol/Desktop/labs/keyring-program/target/release/build/blake3-12de8fac38a452a2/out/c/blake3_neon.o" "-c" "c/blake3_neon.c"
  cargo:warning=In file included from c/blake3_neon.c:1:
  cargo:warning=c/blake3_impl.h:4:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
  cargo:warning=#include <assert.h>
  cargo:warning=         ^~~~~~~~~~
  cargo:warning=1 error generated.
  exit status: 1

  --- stderr


  error occurred: Command "/Users/joesol/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.16.1/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/clang" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "--target=arm64-apple-darwin" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-std=c11" "-o" "/Users/joesol/Desktop/labs/keyring-program/target/release/build/blake3-12de8fac38a452a2/out/c/blake3_neon.o" "-c" "c/blake3_neon.c" with args "clang" did not execute successfully (status code exit status: 1).
```

Answer (score 7):

If you're on Mac and also running into this issue, you basically need to add a compiler flag for `$HOME/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.16.1/solana-release/bin/sdk/sbf/dependencies/platform-tools/llvm/bin/clang`.

You can see from the debug output I posted above, the compiler is designed to look for many different `C*` options/flags. The one that fixed it for me isn't listed in the debug output, even if you use `--verbose`.

In my case, I solved this issue by:

- Making sure I had [Xcode installed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13_4_1-release-notes) - either through the CLI with `xcode-select --install` or the AppStore - setting `
- Installing `gcc-12` with `brew install gcc@12`
- Setting `CPATH` to the right location for `include` files (detailed below)

I did some digging around my machine and found that the typical `/usr/include` directory was missing from my Mac, and `/usr/local/include` only had NodeJS items. However, I was able to find a ton of header files inside of `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include`.

Viola!

```
export CPATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
```

Or, more permanently:

```
sudo echo 'export CPATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"' >> ~/.zshrc
```